# Float on <li> is not working on absolute position

Tags: css

I want to display (blue) sub menu in one line but somehow it is coming in multiple lines. It works fine if I add fixed width but it should be flexible as this menu will by dynamic and could be change as per user's request.

Please check Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/awaises/meXB9/

HTML :

```
<div class="left-bar">
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">For Sale</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Residential</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Commercial</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Industrial</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Agriculture</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Land</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Rent To Own</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Key Money</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">For Sale at Auction</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
body{font:normal 12px/24px arial;}
.left-bar{background:#262626; width:150px; text-align:center; text-decoration}
ul.menu, ul.sub-menu, ul.sub-menu2{margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}
ul.menu li{ position:relative; }
ul.menu li a{
    color:#adadad;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-bottom:1px solid #171717;
    display:block;
    }
ul.sub-menu{
    position:absolute;
    background:#1ea3d7;
    top:2px; left:150px;
    }
ul.sub-menu li{float:left;}
ul.sub-menu li a{color:#fff;border:none;padding:0 10px;}
```

Answer (score 4):

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ajey/9t3Rv/1/)

make `top:0px;` in `ul.sub-menu`

Update:
use `display:inline-flex;`

Comment: Thanks dude for the quick response but don't need this. I want blue sum menu in one line. Right now it is in multi-lines. Is it possible to do this without giving fixed width to the blue menu?

Comment: check the update!. Accept the answer, if the purpose of the question is solved.

Comment: Thanks dude, but it doesn't support IE9 and IE10 :)

Answer (score 0):

Use following.

```
.sub-menu {
    display: table;
}
.sub-menu li {
    /* float: left; */
    display: table-cell;
}
```