# Change <ul> width as per number of <li>

Tags: jquery, css

Can we change the `<ul>` width as per number of `<li>`?

Example:

1. `<li> = 100px of <ul> width`
2. `<li> = 200px of <ul> width`
3. `<li> = 300px of <ul> width`
4. `<li> = 400px of <ul> width`
5. `<li> = 500px of <ul> width`
6. `<li> = 600px of <ul> width`

and so on....

Comment: why your **ul** is inside **li** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('ul').each(function() {
    $(this).width($(this).find('li').length*100);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**CSS** *is all you neeed*

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/belir/2/edit)

Just give `dispaly:inline-block` in CSS to your UL

Comment: Your code has a fixed width of 100px, the asker wants the parent `ul` to increase width the more children it has

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady and that's exactly what my code does: `UL` increases it's width for every `LI` element inside it. Which is pretty trivial. As you can see from the OP's question every LI has a width of `100px`. What's not clear here?

Comment: when i think of it now yea i guess you're right, was just having a slow moment, sorry :D

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not using just `width: auto;`?

```
ul{
 width: auto;
}
li{
 display: inline-block;
}
```

will work for you!

---

Or, if you wanted to do it with jQuery, you can do as others suggested like this:

```
var liwidth = $(ul li).length * 100;
$('ul').css('width',liwidth);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
var cache = $('ul')
cache.width(cache.children('li').length * 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you dare use JS.

What's wrong with

```
li {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried but it is not working in my case that's why I want to fix the issue via JS. Can you solve this issue via css? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190567/float-on-li-is-not-working-on-absolute-position

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

**HTML**

```
<ul id="pr">
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>List-1</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>List-2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>List-3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
var pr = $('#pr').children('li');
$.each(pr,function(k,v){
     $(this).children('ul').width(k*100+100);  
})
```

**jsfiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/2N9Es/2/